# React router not working on live production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, vercel

I have built a UI amazon-clone with create-react-app
it only shows dummy data.
the problem is after publishing it to Vercel, the routing not working as expected! after clicking the links you see a blank page "URL params are correct", you have to manually reload the page to work!
also if you clicked a button no event trigger and you get a blank page!

I wrapped all my routes to MainRoute Component:

```
const MainRoute = withRouter(({ location }) => {
return (
<>
  {location.pathname !== "/login" && location.pathname !== "/signup" ? (
    <Header />
  ) : null}
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home />} />
    <Route exact path="/products" render={() => <Products />} />
    <Route
      exact
      path="/products/:productID"
      render={() => <ProductPage />}
    />
    <Route path="/checkout" render={() => <Checkout />} />
    <Route path="/payment" render={() => <Payment />} />
    <Route path="/login" render={() => <Login />} />
    <Route path="/signup" render={() => <Signup />} />

    <Route render={() => <NotFoundPage />} />
  </Switch>
  {location.pathname !== "/login" && location.pathname !== "/signup" ? (
    <Footer />
   ) : null}
 </>
 );
});

 export default withRouter(MainRoute);
```

my App Component:

```
function App() {

return (
 <div className="app_wrapper">
  <Router>
    <MainRoute />
  </Router>
  </div>
 );
 }

export default App;
```

repo
https://github.com/aseelban/amazon-clone-app
link:
https://amazon-clone-app-llyl1tfcn.vercel.app/

Comment: Is `/checkout` route working perfectly on your local machine? Does this problem occur only on production?

Comment: unfortunately only /login and /singup working! the rest not.
yes everything working fine on localhost

Comment: You don't need to use `withRouter`, you can use `useHistory` hook to get access to `history` object. I think that might be an issue.

Comment: Check https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory for how and where to use `useHistory`.  Use the `useHistory` only when you need access to `history` object, no need to use it in those components (functional) where you don't need access to `history` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone for the help.
I solved this problem by removing HOC withStyles and instead use react-jss.

Answer (score 0):

it works correctly `(under Brave browser)` the authentication routes, could you please specify which route the issue occurs.!

Comment: try to use google chrome, it not work on all routes except the Login and Signup.

Comment: go check console output errors in your production version

Comment: it shows length undefined error: 
react-dom.production.min.js:152 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Ko (react-dom.production.min.js:152)
    at ia (react-dom.production.min.js:160)
    at Object.aa [as useEffect] (react-dom.production.min.js:160)
    at Object.t.useEffect (react.production.min.js:24)
    at dn (makeStyles.js:191)
    at p (makeStyles.js:228)
    at withStyles.js:55
    at Xo (react-dom.production.min.js:153)
    at Na (react-dom.production.min.js:173)
    at vl (react-dom.production.min.js:265)

Comment: it's hard to debug the minify production build.

Comment: you could deploy with developing react version instead